# boost::asio packet order and contiguity

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio

I am using `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket`to send and receive data in a client/server application. I use simple selfmade data packets consisting of a header containing the size of the packet plus some flags and the "real" data.
I send my packets using `boost::asio::write`. In some cases I have a lot of packets to send to one client. Naive the fastest option would be to send them all at once. E.g.

```
 async_write(socket, buffer(p[0].str(),p[0].size()), &callback);
 async_write(socket, buffer(p[1].str(),p[1].size()), &callback);
 async_write(socket, buffer(p[2].str(),p[2].size()), &callback);
```

But if I do it like this, is there a guarantee that my packets arrive as a whole at the client? So in the example if the first 4 bytes of the packet represent the size of the remaining packet, can I call four times

```
uint32 size;
read(socket, buffer(&size,4));
char data[size];
read(socket, buffer(data,size));
```

and be sure that each `data` contains one packet (appart from the size uint32)? Or would it work if I send the next packet in the callback function?

If this infact works one other question is about the ordering. Can I be sure that the order, the packets arrive at the client, is the same as the one I send them from the server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, TCP sockets operate on streams of data, not packets. Secondly the [`async_write()` documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html) explicitly states a single outstanding operation per socket can be in-flight:

> This operation is implemented in terms of zero or more calls to the
>   stream's `async_write_some` function, and is known as a composed
>   operation. The program must ensure that the stream performs no other
>   write operations (such as `async_write`, the stream's `async_write_some`
>   function, or any other composed operations that perform writes) until
>   this operation completes.

You will need to chain your operations: invoke a second `async_write()` only after the completion handler for the first operation has been invoked.

Comment: Ok, I see that problem. But does this on the other hand mean, that it would suffice to call the next async_write in the callback function to ensure packet contiguity and order at the client?

Comment: @Haatschii that is exactly what my answer indicates.

Comment: no problem, feel free to ask other questions if you have them. The `Boost.Asio` library is a bit complex at first.